# Дан вектор x и матрица А. Умножить все четные столбцы матрицы А на вектор x в обратном порядке

Tags: python, numpy

Умножить все четные столбцы матрицы А на вектор x в обратном порядке.

Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить ошибку. По заданию нужно умножить столбцы на вектор, а умножаются строки.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.randint(3, size=(4,3))
x = np.random.randint(3, size=(3,1))
m = np.arange(0,A.shape[0],2)
b=A[m].dot(x[::-1])
print(A)
print(x)
print(b)
s=0
for row in b:
  s+=sum(row)
print(s)
```